# Order entries by "recently modified" date time in control panel

Tags: control-panel, datetime, ordering

Ok somebody ought to start asking the Totally Green questions, it may as well be me.  How do I show the date and time an entry was last manipulated in the control panel?

I produce video more than websites, though that is rapidly changing, and will so even more as the canvas becomes the new After Effects, so I am giving up and in and I'm going to ask all the questions total neophytes would, if it's okay with you people.  Eventually I'm gonna announce my first plug-in, pat myself on the back, and drink a shot.

Comment: You want to see it in the control panel, or output it on the front end? Also, your question doesn't match what you're asking in the description.

Comment: I want to see it in the control panel.  I do not want to output it on the front end.  If they are ordered by when they were last manipulated, that is fine.  What should I change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer** is, you can't.

**Long answer**... [Ian has some good advice](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1346/45), but the Post Date won't update automatically. Your best solution would be to update the Post Date every time you update something else in the entry. Then your Post Date will essentially represent your "last changed" date.

**Bonus answer**... If/when you *do* build your own plugin, you can look into building your own Element Type. (Just a fair warning... building a custom Element Type is a little more advanced.) When you're setting up your Element Type, you can define which columns appear in that "list" view. One of the native columns in every Craft DB table is "dateUpdated", which contains exactly the information you're looking for. Just output that as one of your columns, and voila!

**There's no rush, I can wait answer**... the ability to add custom, sortable columns to the entries (and users, assets, etc.) index pages is coming “Real Soon Now”™.

Comment: It's actually the time I am looking for as much as the time as I have an employee entering data for me who seems to be on the "there's no rush" plan". There seems to be a long time (a few texts to the gf?) in between posts.  I wanted to confront the situation with data, not feelings... I can get it manually, however, so all is not lost while I learn php on the side :-)

Comment: Next time I'm not waiting 4 days to ask the question while I hunt and peck for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Click 'Post Date' in your entries view. You can then toggle ascending or descending.

[image: Entries view sorting by post date]

Comment: Ian this is only true for "Post Date" and "Expire Date". A "Last Modified Date" column is not available, but I can remember Brandon saying it is on "The List" to make the table user editable (add custom fields to it, etc.). Hopefully this will come as a 2.x update.